# Using config file in .NET Standard does not work

Tags: c#, .net-standard, configuration-files

How can you use a console config file (App.config) in a .NET Standard project.

I have one console application with in the App.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Test" value="test" />
</appSettings>
```

In my .NET Standard project I added the NuGet package:

```
Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -Version 4.5.0
```

And have a class that returns the value of that Key:

```
public string Test()
        {  
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"];
        }
```

This is just to test if I could use App.config settings in a .NET Standard project.

But I get this error message:

*System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'*

When I do this in Program.cs:

```
Class class = new Class();
string result = class.Test();
```

Comment: I have a console app that does exactly what you're doing.  Could it be a version issue?

Comment: Perhaps a problem with package versions? You installed version 4.5.0 and it's looking for 4.0.1.0.

Comment: @Duston really xD...

Comment: @DanielA.White well Duston says in his comment it works for him?

Comment: @user7849697 but he dosen't specify he is using the same versions as you

Comment: I tried to edit my comment to say that I wasn't using the same versions (the project is .NET 4 and the DLLs are 4.0.0.0) but my 5 minutes had expired before I got there.

Comment: Well it works if you install in both projects the NuGet System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -Version 4.5.0 package as Leo Hinojosa said

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the behavior you mentioned, and to fix it I referenced the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -Version 4.5.0` on the Console project that consumes the test class.

The error is basically telling you that it cannot find that assembly in the output path, you referenced it in your .net standard project but it also needs to be referenced in the Console App that is launching the project.

That being said, also make sure that your config file `<appSettings>` section is under the `<configuration>` section such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Test" value="test" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works indeed. So you have to add this reference Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -Version 4.5.0  both to the .NET Standard and Console/UWP/WPF/... project?

Comment: Yes, the Console Project needs to a reference to the configuration types to be able to process the file. Then additional projects that need to read these settings can reference the ConfigurationManager objects, then the  ConfigurationManager class knows how to fetch that same stored information.